# Are fprintf, fputs... functions on windows legal according to the C standard?

Tags: c++, c, windows

I was wondering: why does writing in a file with the standard lib converts your `\n` into `\r\n`? Is it standard behaviour according `C99` or a "commidity" added by `MS`? If it is standard, with the old Apple convention `(\r)`, would writing `"toto\n"` to a file write `"toto\r"`? Is the current behaviour here so that you could read UNIX file but UNIXes could not read yours?(I love conspiracy theories)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. > why does writing in a file with the standard lib converts your \n into \r\n?

   It's to make code more portable; you can just use `\n` in your program and have it work on UNIX, Windows, Macs, and (supposedly) everything else.
2. > Is it standard behaviour according C99 or a "commidity" added by MS?

   Yes, it's standard.
3. > If it is standard, with the old Apple convention (\r), would writing "toto\n" to a file write "toto\r"?

   Yes, translating end-of-line characters is expected.
4. > Is the current behaviour here so that you could read UNIX file but UNIXes could not read yours?

   No, there's no conspiracy.

From the C11 spec, **§7.21.2 Streams**, ¶2:

> … Characters may have to be added, altered, or deleted on input and output to conform to differing conventions for representing text in the host environment. Thus, there need not be a one-to-one correspondence between the characters in a stream and those in the external representation. …

If you don't want this behaviour, open your file as a binary stream rather than as a text stream.